# Im building a React App that requires a pdf to download, in the event the (materialUI) download button is clicked, how can I add that functionality?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**the profile component contains the following code:**

```
<div className="button_container" style={{display:'flex'}}>
      
       <DownloadButton text={'PDF'} icon={<GetAppIcon />} /> 
</div>
```

**the button component contains the following code:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import './Button.css'


const DownloadButton = ({text, icon}) => {
    return ( 
       <Button onClick={() => { }} className="custom_btn" endIcon={icon ?
 (<div className="btn_icon_container" >{icon}</div>) : null}>
            <span className="btn_textw">{text}</span>
       </Button>
    )
}

export default CustomButton
```

**I've added an onClick event but am having difficulty figuring the simplest way to trigger the file to download, once the button is clicked **

Any comments are appreciated

Comment: download button should have the live link, and it will automatically download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use an [HTML anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and style it like a button.

```
<a href="/path/to/file.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

With material core buttons you need to add the [href prop](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) and it will use an anchor tag instead of a button tag.

```
<Button href="/path/to/file.pdf">Download PDF</Button>
```

Your download button would look like

```
const DownloadButton = ({text, icon}) => {
    const endIcon = icon ? (<div className="btn_icon_container" >{icon}</div>) : null;
    return ( 
       <Button href="file.pdf" className="custom_btn" endIcon={endIcon}>
           <span className="btn_textw">{text}</span>
       </Button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your button into a link and provide the path to your pdf file

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import './Button.css'


const DownloadButton = ({text, icon}) => {
    return ( 
       <Button component="a" href="PATH_TO_YOUR_PDF_FILE" className="custom_btn" endIcon={icon ?
 (<div className="btn_icon_container" >{icon}</div>) : null}>
            <span className="btn_textw">{text}</span>
       </Button>
    )
}

export default CustomButton
```